# Sort the values in a set in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting

I have a method returned a Set [method which returns the solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecyws.png).

```
    public Set<DesignerSolution> getDesignerSolutions() {
    return designerSolutions;
}
```

DesignerSolution object has a junction position, i have to sort in ascending order based on that position.
[junction position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkzhf.png)
Array which is getting returned.
[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESJWu.png)
please see the attached images in the highlighted text.

Comment: Please provide actual code instead of images.

Comment: Use a `TreeSet` and either make the `DesignerSolution` sort naturally by `junctionPosition` by implementing `Comparable<DesignerSolution>`, or supply a `Comparator<DesignerSolution>` to the `TreeSet` constructor.

Comment: *FYI:* A `Set` is not an *array*. Please stop saying that. --- *"I do have a set method"* No, you have a method *returned* a `Set`. A "set method" means something else. --- *"In that array there is a junction position"* No, the `DesignerSolution` object has a junction position.

Comment: Usually a set has no order, it's just like in mathematics: a set has elements, and that's it. That said, you can use e.g., a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) that will preserve the order of the elements as they were inserted.

Comment: I tried this       public Set<DesignerSolution> getDesignerSolutions() {
  //TreeSet<DesignerSolution> ts = new TreeSet<DesignerSolution> ();
  //ts.addAll(designerSolutions);
  return ts;
 }     ---- Did not work out

Comment: `return new TreeSet<>(designerSolutions)` would be shorter, and only works if `DesignerSolution` implements `compareTo()` correctly. Edit the question and show what you have, if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.sort(array, comparator) in Java. Where *comparator* is for your specific class to tell it based on which field to sort on:

```
class SortbyJunction implements Comparator<DesignerSolution>
{
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of junction
    public int compare(DesignerSolution a, DesignerSolution b)
    {
        return a.junction - b.junction;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new SortbyJunction());
```

To get your array sorted